# How can I get "Word Wrap (Visual Line mode)" behavior by default, for all buffers?

Tags: emacs, word-wrap

Whenever I start Emacs (GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30)), I turn on visual line mode (`Line Wrapping in This Buffer -> Word Wrap (Visual Line mode)`) for any file I want to edit:

[image: Word Wrap (Visual Line mode)]

How can I make Emacs turn it on automatically on every file (so that I don't have to do it manually)?

Comment: @Drew Does it mean that if I modify `menu-bar.el` now, I will need to change the way to fix the bug after I migrate to Emacs 27?

Comment: If you intend to use both an old release and a release where it is fixed then use conditional code, e.g. `(when (< emacs-major version 27) ____)`.

Comment: @Drew I think I will wait until Emacs 27 comes out. It is not that annoying. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for that menu item and the other **Line Wrapping in This Buffer items** is in file `menu-bar.el`. You can perhaps use that code for inspiration to create what you need. See also the Emacs manual, node [Visual Line Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html). See also Emacs bug #[39848](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=39848).

This bug (regression actually) has been fixed in the development code for Emacs 27 (not yet released).